# CCNet - Delete working copy before MSBuild?

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn-server

I'm setting up a continuous integration environment, using VisualSVN Server and CrusieControl.NET. 
What I want to do is delete the working copy before the MSBuild task starts?

I have read that I could use Nant or a Batch file which ccnet would invoke.
What is best practice here?
Any help on this would me great!

here is an extract of the  section of ccnet.config

```
      <tasks>
        <msbuild>
            <ItemGroup>
                <FilesToDelete Include="C:\CruiseControl\Working\\\**\*"/>
            </ItemGroup>
            <Target Name="Task" DependsOn="Preparation">
                  build
            </Target>
            <Target Name="Preparation">
                  <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />
            </Target-->
            <executable>                                                      
                C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe                                              
            </executable> 
            <projectFile>Example.sln</projectFile>  
            <buildArgs>
                /p:Configuration=Release /p:MSBuildExtensionsPath=C:\Progra~2\MSBuild /p:MSBuildEmitSolution=1 /verbosity:minimal
            </buildArgs>                                                      
            <logger>
                C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll
            </logger>
        </msbuild>
      </tasks>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer to my original question:

I simply had to put the cleanCopy true inside the sourcecontrol block.

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">                                            
    <trunkUrl>TRUNK-URL</trunkUrl>                
    <executable>SVN.EXE</executable>           
    <username>TEST</username>                                         
    <password>TEST</password> 
    <cleanCopy>true</cleanCopy>         
  </sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think modifying msbuild script is the easiest solution here.
Deleting the working copy is not part of the build itself, it is part of the cc .net build process though. You need it when you build with cc.net, not when you build with VS or else.

What I would do is either do it with batch, powershell or a msbuild script. Deleting a directory is straightforward so I would recommend to do it with batch :

```
<prebuild>
     <exec>
        <executable>cmd.exe</executable>
        <buildArgs>/c "if exist "C:\CruiseControl\Working" rd /s /q "C:\CruiseControl\Working""</buildArgs>
    </exec>
</prebuild>

<tasks>

    <msbuild>
        <executable>                                                      
            C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe                                              
        </executable> 
        <projectFile>Example.sln</projectFile>  
        <buildArgs>
            /p:Configuration=Release /p:MSBuildExtensionsPath=C:\Progra~2\MSBuild /p:MSBuildEmitSolution=1 /verbosity:minimal
        </buildArgs>                                                      
        <logger>
            C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll
        </logger>
    </msbuild>
  </tasks>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it deleted the contents of the folder but the build failed with following error:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Do i need to get the code from subversion again after this? Is there anything else i need here?

Comment: Why do you want to remove this working directory? What's inside? It appears CC .net cannot delete it because it is in use.

Comment: The working svn code is in here.I want to remove the working directory so as It can do a fresh clean build!.

Comment: Ok. You must do the delete in the prebuild section (not in the tasks one). The ccnet operation flow is here : http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/FAQ I strongly recomment that you read some basic docs about CC .net like http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2008/06/01/cruisecontrolnet-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: Ok thanks again - My Build is still failing though, Should I be doing something like this <prebuild>
    <exec>
   <executable>cmd.exe</executable>
   <buildArgs>/c "if exist "C:\PortalCruiseControl\Working" rd /s /q "C:\PortalCruiseControl\Working""</buildArgs>
    </exec>
    </prebuild> just before the <tasks> section?

Comment: I cannot help you without logs. I suggest you create a new question with your current project configuration, your error message and a brief description of what you've tried. This would be cleaner for the readers. By the way, I edited my answer with the prebuild thing.

Comment: OK thanks for all your help, I'm still getting the error: he process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. I'll post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you could actually make the first part of your MSBuild task prepare the release directory by doing the cleanup

you could do it by domain something similar to this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToDelete Include="<PathGoesHere>\**\*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Task" DependsOn="Preparation">
      //normal task happens here
</Target>

<Target Name="Preparation">
      <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: @PaulStack: I tried doing this but it did not seem to work? I set the path of the working directory i.e.                       <FilesToDelete Include="C:\PortalCruiseControl\Working\**\*"/>

Comment: you need a \ after Working so like this <FilesToDelete Include="C:\PortalCruiseControl\Working\**\*"/>

Comment: It still doesn't work I have tried the extra \ . Could I possibly be doing something else wrong? the item group should be inside the <msbuild>?

Comment: sorry was away early yesterday - can u show me your msbuild script? you can hide any areas of sensitivity if you need to

Comment: thats ok - I have added the msbuild script to the question.

Comment: The code Paul gave you is to be inserted in a msbuild script, not in your cc.net config. In your case, you need to create a new file (you can not add msbuild code into your sln file) as shown in this tuto : http://codingcockerel.co.uk/2008/04/15/automating-the-build-with-msbuild/